# How to stop SMS Preview in programmatically

Tags: ios

Can we able to make show preview off.In Settings-->messages-->show preview--> ON/OFF, this is the action we have to perform programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

This falls outside of your application sandbox.  From the docs:

> #### The Application Sandbox
>
> For security reasons, iOS restricts
>   each application (including its preferences and data) to a unique
>   location in the file system. This restriction is part of the security
>   feature known as the application’s sandbox. The sandbox is a set of
>   fine-grained controls limiting an application’s access to files,
>   preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. Each application
>   has access to the contents of its own sandbox but cannot access other
>   applications’ sandboxes.

You may find a way to do it, but it's an absolute no-go unless you're developing for jailbroken devices.  If you do find a way to accomplish this and plan to submit to the App Store, Rest assured, Apple will find this functionality in the review process and would reject it based solely on this functionality.